# SSIS Send email from package that is off the domain

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, ssis, smtp, exchange-server

I have a SSIS package that is deployed to server that is not on a domain but it is within our network perimeter.  I would like to be able to send an email on package failure but being off the domain presents a challenge that I have not faced before.

Using a dummy gmail account is not acceptable to the business.

I would like to use the company SMTP server (mail.somecompany.com) but I do not know how to do this while off the domain.  Can someone please tell me if this is possible and what steps I need to take.

Useful information:

SQL Server 2016

Project Deployment mode

Visual Studio 2015

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use script task for sending mail.

This might can help you:

```
  MailMessage Mymsg = new MailMessage();
        SmtpClient smptserver = new SmtpClient();

System.Net.Mail.Attachment attach;
        Mymsg.From = new MailAddress("aa@abc.com");

       String Tolist = Convert.ToString("a@aa.com");
        String CClist = Convert.ToString("a@xse.com");
        String BCClist = Convert.ToString("ba@aas.com");

        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(Tolist))
            Mymsg.To.Add(Tolist);
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(CClist))
            Mymsg.CC.Add(CClist);
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(BCClist))
            Mymsg.Bcc.Add(BCClist);

        Mymsg.Subject = "Subject!";
        Mymsg.Body = "Hi, Your message!";

        Mymsg.IsBodyHtml = true;



        try
        {
            smptserver.Send(Mymsg);
            Console.WriteLine("OK");
        }
        catch (System.Net.Mail.SmtpException ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.StatusCode.ToString());
        }

        Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;
        smptserver = null;
        Mymsg = null;
```

Comment: Thanks, will try this as soon as i get a moment.  Another solution to this would be to set up msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail on the server.  Then use execute sql tasks to send the alerts.

Comment: Thanks for this.  I got the AWS expert to set up dbmail to work off the domain instead.